# Call SetAlpha in widget application

Tags: android, imageview

I have a ImageView as background of appWidgets layout. So I want to change both background resource (nine patch image) and background transparency. I tried as below:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setBackgroundColor", 0);
rv.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setBackgroundResource", nBackgroundId);  // set background_id
rv.setInt(R.id.widget_background, "setAlpha", nTransparency);  // set transparent
```

But nothing is happened, could anybody tell me the solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Which version is your android sdk? It requires Froyo or greater